# Getting this specific output from vscode on MacOS 12.6.1 Monterey ESP32

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, esp32, platformio

Im currently working on a project with my esp32 and an analog thermometer(Using platformio and the C language extension). I used the following code on my windows machine and had no issues, yet when trying it out on my mac i get the following output instead of the reading of the temperatures.

```
#include <Arduino.h> // Library included with PlatformIO

const int tempPin = 2; // analog input pin constant

int tempVal; // temperature sensor raw readings

float volts; // variable for storing voltage

float tempC; // temperature variable in Degrees Celcius

float tempF; // temperature variable in Degrees Farenheit

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(921600);
  Serial.println("Hello from the setup");
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  tempVal = analogRead(tempPin);

  volts = tempVal / 1023.0; // normalize by the maximum temperature raw reading range

  tempC = (volts - 0.5) * 100; // calculate temperature celsius from voltage as per the equation found on the sensor spec sheet.

  tempF = ((volts - 0.5) * 100) * 1.8 + 32;

  Serial.print(" Temperature is:   "); // print out the following string to the serial monitor
  Serial.print(tempC);                 // in the same line print the temperature
  Serial.println(" degrees C\n");      // still in the same line print degrees C, then go to next line.

  Serial.print(" Temperature is:   "); // print out the following string to the serial monitor
  Serial.print(tempF);                 // in the same line print the temperature
  Serial.println(" degrees F\n");

  delay(1000); // wait for 1 second or 1000 milliseconds before taking the next reading.
}
```

Id appreciate any help since im fairly new to using VSCode and am not very familiar with the esp32 either. Thanks in advance.

[VsCodeOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJS22.jpg)

I tried changing the display language from en(default) to spanish (which is another language I tend to use in my computer) but to no results.

Comment: just copy and paste the text. why are you posting images?

Comment: �Q���ո)^鸵^␆�嚂�뺜␋�ͧV�퐐ȊRͭź(�嵪嚂��ڂ�k���Vű␖␚   ��ݰ)V�V
�嚂�㲙%�շV�吘ԊBŵպ8�嵪嚵����␖���Fű␖␚     ��ݰ)V�^␎�嚂��␓��␋�ɷ^�倈ІRյɲ,�ᥪ횂��➐␃���Vյ␞␚␕�ᐭݰ-N�V␖�횂�␃��␆�ųV�吘ԊRͭź(�嵪嚂��斖␋�ͧ␋V��HȂ��ٰ-N�V␖�횂�␃��␓�շ^�合��Rյɲ,�ᥪ횂���$���Jɵ␎␒␑��ݰ)N�V
�嚂�␃��␋�ɷ^�퐐؂RͽͲ(�鲵�嚂���ʐ�Ͳ�vA�Q���ݰ)V�V
�嚂�␓��␋�ɷ^�倔؂RɽͲ(�鵢嚂���,���N͵␎␒␙��ݰ)V�V
�嚂�␃��␖�ɷN�퐐ȊRͭ�ź(�鵢嚂��斖␋�ͧN��HȊ��ݰ)V�^␎�嚂�␓��␋�ɷN�퐐؂RɽͲ(�鵢嚂���,���Nͥ␎␒␙��ݰ)V�^␎�嚂�␓��␖�ͧN�퐐ȂRͽŲ(�鵪嚂��斖␋�ͧ␋N��HȊ��ݰ)V�^␎�嚂�␋���␖�ͧV�퐐ȊRͭź(�鵢嚂��斖␋�ͧN��HȊ��ո9^�V␖�횂�␃���␓�շ^�倔؂RɽͲ(�鵢嚂���ʐ�Ͳ�vA�Q���ݰ)V�V
�嚂�#��$�ųV�퐘ԊRŵź(�嵪嚂�,V��␖�ͧN��HȂ��ո9^�V␖�

This is an example. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: 921600 is very high speed for the serial port. Try 115200.

Comment: @romkey thanks for the response, I tried it but still haven't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you're using wrong serial port try changing on vscode